# How to debug Detect Displays? Having trouble using an external monitor

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard, display, displayport

I have a MacBookPro (MacBookPro5,4) with the DVI output connection and I can't seem to get it to connect to my Dell Monitor.  I've tried using Detect displays and made sure the monitor is using the DVI input.  It says there's no power coming from the cable and enters power save.  Detect Displays does nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: @Griffo nope, I'll check that out.  possible that's the problem

Comment: I've seen that happen before but it's never been my computer.  In my case, once it was a broken monitor, another time it was a dodgy cable.  There are different types of DVI cables so make sure you have the correct one for both MacBook and monitor.

Comment: Which inputs/outputs are you using exactly? You say you've using DVI output from the MBP and DVI input on the display, but the question is tagged "displayport". I'm guessing that you're actually using the mini DisplayPort out on the MBP + a mini DisplayPort-DVI adapter/cable, right? Also, when you say "Detect Displays does nothing," does that mean that Displays Preferences doesn't show an attached external display?

Answer (score 1):

A few steps to try:

Try a different cable
Try a different screen
Try a different laptop/macbook

If you get success with one of these then the problem probably lies with whatever you left out, after that you'll have to try combinations of the above.